# Chosen drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I need to change the options of a drop-down list according to a selection.
I would like to use a chosen drop-down list.

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I made a fiddle and it works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/3hkhcycg/12/

The problem is that I can't make it work in my project.
I am afraid I don't include the right things in the right place.

That's how and where I include stuff.

At the end of head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/docsupport/prism.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/chosen.css">
```

Somewhere before head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
//HTML code that describes my elements
//JS code in a script tag with jquery
```

I've notice that:

- if I put JS code inside `$(document).ready`

  - it gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function`
- if it's outside `$(document).ready`

  - there is no error, the drop-down field looks like a chosen drop-down, but it doesn't change the content according to selection.
- if it's outside `$(document).ready` and I remove `$(".chosen_class").chosen({ width:"90%"})`

  - it changes the content but, of course, it does not look like a chosen drop-down

Update: 
I need drop-downs for a pop-up which is activated from a JS class.
There is a lot of code, I will show here the relevant one.

```
MyClass.prototype.showPopUp= function(){
     document.getElementById('my_div').style.display = "block";
}
<div id="my_div" style = "display:none;">
    <form>
        <select id="select1" >
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select2" class="chosen_class" data-placeholder="Select here" multiple>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chosen_class").chosen({
        width:"90%"
    });
    $("#select1").change(function () {
        var letter = $(this).val();
        $('#select2').empty();
        if (letter == "A") {
            $('#select2')
                .append("<option value='letter A'>letter A</option>")
                .trigger("chosen:updated");
        } else if (letter == "B") {
            $('#select2')
                .append("<option value='letter B'>letter B</option>")
                .trigger("chosen:updated");
        } else if (letter == "C") {
            $('#select2')
                .append("<option value='letter C'>letter C</option>")
                .trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
    });
});
```

Everything is in  myFile.php
I include this file in my project like this:

```
           <?php require_once(ROOTPATH."/myFile.php"); ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write that you add the references to the jquery libraries "Somewhere before head"? It should be part of the head section, or even better, just before the close of the body section (the lines before </body>).

Comment: Everything I said it's "Somewhere before head" it's written in a different file and is included with "require_once", before <head> starts. So you say I should put all the libraries in the end of the body section. Where should I include my HTML code? Does it matter the order: HTML code, JS code?

Comment: I tried to insert this

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../Libs/chosen_v1.6.2/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

just before the close of the body section.
And it gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function

Comment: @Newbie: did updated my answer so as to illustrate the way you should go about it when templating. Try it and update the community on the result. Hope this helps address your challenge!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <!-- Your chosen.css file -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML and select element to be affected here -->


    <!-- jQuery library declaration here;
    please note: this should come before your chosen JavaScript files.
    The order is very important -->
    <!-- Your chosen JavaScript files here -->
    <!-- Then, initialise chosen here so as to affect your desired element -->
</body>
</html>
```

In summary and in required order, using the code from your shared [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hkhcycg/12/) and taking in consideration your last update while templating;

Here, it is assumed your main file is named `index.php` and at the same directory level as your my file named `myFile.php` which is to contain your actual code; as such, you can achieve your intended purpose as follow:

Content of your **`index.php`** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php require_once("myFile.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Content of your **`myFile.php`** file:

```
<div id="my_div" style = "display:none;">
    <form>
        <select id="select1" >
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select2" class="chosen_class" data-placeholder="Select here" multiple>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // All manipulation begins here.
        MyClass.prototype.showPopUp= function(){
            document.getElementById('my_div').style.display = "block";
        };

        $(".chosen_class").chosen({
            width:"90%"
        });
        $("#select1").change(function () {
            var letter = $(this).val();
            $('#select2').empty();
            if (letter == "A") {
                $('#select2')
                    .append("<option value='letter A'>letter A</option>")
                    .trigger("chosen:updated");
            } else if (letter == "B") {
                $('#select2')
                    .append("<option value='letter B'>letter B</option>")
                    .trigger("chosen:updated");
            } else if (letter == "C") {
                $('#select2')
                    .append("<option value='letter C'>letter C</option>")
                    .trigger("chosen:updated");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Remember: for the purpose of the illustration above, it is assumed both **`index.php`** and **`myFile.php`** are located at the same level in your selected directory.

Comment: I respected your guidelines and the result looks like a chosen drop-down but it does't update options as select1 says.
I inserted my code (in this order: HTML, jquery libs, chosen JS files, my JS code, initialize chosen) before the end of the body tag.

Do you have any idea why is wrong to intialize chosen inside `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: Just updated my answer with an illustration from your shared jsfiddle, following my recommendation; you may simply copy and paste it in order to test it.

Comment: @Newbie: hope you got it working in your project now! If not, what challenge are you facing?

Comment: I check it and it's the same comportament. 

If I use the code from your answer, I receive this error: `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> `

If I use the JS code outsite `$(document).ready` I don't have the error anymore but select2 doesn't have any option.

Comment: @Newbie: You should under normal circumstances not get any error if implemented as above. Do you mind updating your post with exactly what your code looks like *(as it is when you get the **`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function`** error)*?

Comment: I updated my question and I hope the context is better described now. I used the code from your answer.

Comment: How do you expect me to help troubleshoot when you don't do exactly as asked? The code you've updated above in your post is not complete for an eventual replication! Anyway, you may do as such if you truly need to get it troubleshooted further otherwise the answer above is adequate to address the challenge you are facing, even if modularised as a template. To your attention: the **`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function`** error you get is an indication that your **`chosen.jquery.min.js`** file doesn't get loaded.

Comment: @Newbie: did a minor update to my post (wrapping the JavaScript code within a `<script>` element); you check edit history.

Comment: Still, why do I receive this error when I have this 

 `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>`

before initializing my chosen element

Comment: You shouldn't be having that error should you have implemented as I've described in my post unless modified in an unsuitable manner @Newbi. Are you sure you are doing the right thing? Do you mind sharing your files hierarchy structure and contents (relating to this post). You may read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post accordingly.